# HTTP request failed Length required

Tags: php, api, httprequest

I humbly come before the people for some much needed assistance with this..

I am using (or trying to use) the skyscanner API - http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0 as documented [here](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingList). But I am coming up against this error:

> HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required

**PHP attempt 1**

```
function getSkyScanner() {

    $url = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0?apiKey=MY-API-KEY';

    $headers = array(   'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Accept' => 'application/xml');

    $contextData = array ( 
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => $headers);

    $context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    if ($result === FALSE) { echo 'error'; }
    var_dump($result);
}
```

My server doesn't support cURL so I'm in need of a solution without it. I'm using localhost with WAMP but I have also tried a live version which comes up with the same error and seemingly same problem. I have tried almost every combination of variables in order to correct the error with a discouraging amount of success (none). This is one such variation including the form contents that I am attempting to send.

**PHP attempt 2**

```
function getSkyScanner() {

    $url = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0?apiKey=MY-API-KEY';

    $params =   array(  'country' => 'GB',
                        'currency' => 'GBP',
                        'locale' => 'en-GB',
                        'originplace' => 'LHR',
                        'destinationplace' => 'EDI',
                        'outbounddate' => '2016-10-10',
                        'adults' => '1'
                );

    $query = http_build_query($params);

    $headers = array(   'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Accept' => 'application/xml');

    $contextData = array ( 
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => $headers,
            'content' => $query );

    $context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    if ($result === FALSE) { echo 'error'; }
    var_dump($result);
}
```

This throws out:

> Content-type not specified

Followed by:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

If you can help I would appreciate some insight right about now.

Many thanks!

Comment: 1. You don't seem to be sending any content / form data with your request. The docs you linked specify what fields are required to be sent. 2. You may need to include a Content-Length header with the size of the data you're sending.

Comment: @Mark H - thanks for your comments. Just to clarify I have edited the post to emphasise the options already explored. 1. Fair point about the form data which you can see in my 2nd attempt (above). 2. Also I have tried various Content-Length headers but to no avail. Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create headers in a wrong way - instead of an array, headers should be passed as a string.

```
$headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
           "Accept: application/xml\r\n";
```

You can use below snippet to create the correct request:

```
function prepare_headers($headers) {
    return
    implode('', array_map(function($key, $value) {
            return "$key: $value\r\n";
        }, array_keys($headers), array_values($headers))
    );
}

function http_post($url, $data, $ignore_errors = false) {
    $data_query = http_build_query($data);
    $data_len = strlen($data_query);

    $headers = array(
      'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept' => 'application/xml',
      'Content-Length' => $data_len
    );

    $response = 
    file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(
        array('http' => array(
                  'method' => 'POST',
                  'header' => prepare_headers($headers),
                  'content' => $data_query,
                  'ignore_errors' => $ignore_errors
                )
        )
    ));

    return (false === $response) ? false : 
        array(
            'headers' => $http_response_header,
            'body' => $response
        );
}
```

Example usage of http_post method:

```
$result = http_post('http://business.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0', array(
  'apiKey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  'country' => 'UK',
  'currency' => 'GBP',
  'locale' => 'en-GB',
  'locationSchema' => 'iata',
  'originplace' => 'EDI',
  'destinationplace' => 'LHR',
  'outbounddate' => '2016-10-10',
  'adults' => '1'
), false);
```

Parameter **$ignore_errors** in http_post method is reponsible for fetching the content even on failure status codes (400, 500, etc.). If you receive **Bad request**, set **ignore_errors = true** -> you'll receive full response from server.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time with this. I have since been able to enable CURL within WAMP and will now have that on my server so I have implemented this which seems a lot less prone to bugs. However as you had taken the time to answer I wanted do the courtesy of checking it. So after putting this code to work I get a **403 Forbidden**  error which (upon ignoring the errors as you suggested) looks to be because the server redirects to the location header - and as the skyscanner documentation specifies this needs to be annexed with the apiKey. ..continued below

Comment: CURL prevents this redirection so that apiKey can be added to the URL but I'm not sure how to do that without CURL. So my answer to your answer is we don't know if it works but it looks like you are on the right lines for with this method - as I say the true test would be to prevent redirection and therefore see the header response. But you get an upvote from me for this effort on heeding the call when it was most needed!

Comment: Have you replaced this part of code **'apiKey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',** with a proper apiKey?

Comment: I've added response headers to function http_post. When apiKey is correct, $result['headers'], should contain **Location** header.

Comment: nicely done. Yes - I had a 'proper' apiKey. The **ignore_errors** suggestion was a good one and it appears to be a very useful way to get data back without redirecting or using CURL. Well played!